# htmlLawed in text format corrupts Scald insert in CKEditor module

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, input-formats, scald

I have [htmlawed](http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/htmLawed_README.htm#s2.3) text format filter. When I enable it for any filter that it is used by any CKEditor profile, it causes corruption for inserted Scald atoms in the CKEditor.

In other words, the following is a correct code for an image atom as shown in CKEDITOR source view:

```
<div class="dnd-atom-wrapper" data-scald-align="none" data-scald-context="sdl_editor_representation" data-scald-options="" data-scald-sid="8" data-scald-type="image">
    <!-- scald embed --></div>
```

After changing the text format to a format that it uses htmlawed and saving the node and then edit it again and switching to Rich Text Editor, I got the following code in CKEDITOR source:

```
<div class="dnd-atom-wrapper" data-scald-align="undefined" data-scald-context="undefined" data-scald-options="" data-scald-sid="undefined" data-scald-type="undefined">
    <!-- scald embed --></div>
```

This cause alerting an error message:

[image]

Just removing htmlawed filter makes ecerything works fine, but this is not an option for me.

I tried the following settings - in the screen shoe - for htmlawed:

[image]

However, it does not work as expected to preserve the scald attributes.

I alse tried to change the order of the filter by making it before or after `Embedded atoms` filter

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The solution, simply, is to change a Security setting of the CKEditor profile meant by this issue as follows:

1 - go to `admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/(TheProfileName)

2 - In Security tab, goto Security Settings and choose `Run security filters only when CKEditor is set to start automatically.`

Of course, you have to notice that CKEditor in this profile is not started automatically.